# How To Push Music Playable Data Streamed From Spotify To A Device That Does Not Use The SDK Provided By Spotify

Tags: ios, spotify

I apologise for the possibility of the title of my question would lead to confusion of the problem. For that I will explain my purpose in detail.

We are currently developing our own wifi speaker which is built with MIPS. The speaker comes with an app that will be used to manage it. One of the features that would we would like to include in the app is accessing contents of Spotify and be able to play them on the speakers.

Unfortunately, after going through the iOS SDK Documentation, and did some tests on Web API Console provided by the official of Spotify, I noticed that Spotify does not allow developers to directly get URL of a song, except for preview purposes. I also wasn't able to find any way to get the data bytes of the music streamed from the server. Every content comes with a corresponding URI which is used for a request.

For the device(WiFi Speaker) part, we recently tried to contact Spotify and ask for an SDK that can be used for development. However, one problem is that Spotify told us that they have SDK for x86, and ARMs architecture only. They don't have MIPS.

Now, here are my questions:

1. Is there any way for me to push music from an app to the WiFi Speakers without having to use SDK (for backend device)?
2. If Spotify can provide an SDK for our device, then how can we integrate the SDK with our platform?

I'll explain my 2nd question for clarity. Like for instance, in Android and iOS, these are popular platforms and are widely used by mobile devices. So if they provide SDKs for the two OS, then they can use default system frameworks to access the player for playing the content. (In iOS, it's the AVFoundation Framework). However, if Spotify were able to provide the SDK that we need, how would we able to integrate that with our own platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer your question no 1:

You should be able to push music from an app using a buffer that you can read from using Core Audio and also forward to a device of your choice. I think what you are looking for can be found at [CocoaLibSpotify](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2012/04/augraph-basics-in-cocoalibspotify/)